# Syspro - Update query for sales prices

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to find any information on SQL scripts for Syspro - Google searches just come up with 3rd party software despite Syspro using a fairly standard looking SQL database.

I'm just wondering if anyone on here has any experience with updating Syspro via SQL updates - I have a client that uses Syspro and they've previously updated it by exporting everything into Access, making changes and updating everything from there - I was told by their out-going IT consultant that this is the only way to update Syspro (which, I suspect, isn't true).

Just looking for some do's and dont's before I go screwing up data!

thanks,

Darren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not advisable to update the SYSPRO database directly. While it is relatively simple to breakdown and track what data is stored where etc. there is more often than not more than 1 place where a field is updated and/or there is an additional flag that is also changed. Further, updating it directly in the database would also get rid of any possible audit trail.

If this needs to be done in bulk (as your question seems to refer) then this would be best done by posting an update using one of the SYSPRO "business objects". Have a look here for more info regarding business objects: [SYSPRO Business Object Library](http://bit.ly/bolibrary)

There are 2 ways you can make use of this: in a custom pane within SYSPRO (no licensing requirements then) or if your customer is licensed for the respective business object you could write an external program to post updates using the business object.

Below is a custom pane I created sometime ago that updates prices of items based on an excel spreadsheet. Save the below code section into a txt file and when in SYSPRO if you click on the drop down arrow (on the top right of any pane) you can select **Customized Pane > Import Customized Pane** and specify this txt file you have saved. This will create the custom pane with title **Pricelist Import**. If you now press the refresh button on this customized pane it's going to ask you for an excel file to base it's update on. By default it will look for a file called **Pricelist Import.xlsx** in the **SYSPRO\Base\Settings** folder of the machine you are working on. You will need to create a spreadsheet with 5 columns and in this order too (StockCode, PriceCode, SellingPrice, PriceBasis, CommisionCode). Once you have a spreadsheet and specify the file at this prompt it will load the contents of the spreadsheet into the listview and by default all entries will be selected to import. If you now press **Update** it will update the prices accordingly and if not possible will return the respective error messages back into the listview.

```
# Customized Panes for 'IMPDH2LZ' Created: 2013/09/17
# PANE:Pricelist Import
[PANE]
CHRISVIMPDH2LZ    01000Pricelist Import                                                                                    020                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               000000500001IMPDH2000M000Update              3362                    00000                          0
[VBSCRIPT]
' This script contains functions for customized pane events.
' You must not modify the name of the functions.
Option Explicit

Public Debug : Debug = "False"

Function CustomizedPane_OnRefresh()
        Dim ImportFilePmt : ImportFilePmt = InputBox("Enter Location of Excel file to Import?",  "Pricelist Import File", SystemVariables.CodeObject.baseSettingsFolder &"Pricelist Import.xlsx")
        Dim objExcel : Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        On error resume next
        Dim objWorkbook : Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ImportFilePmt)
        If err then
            If ImportFilePmt <> "" then
            msgbox "Error Importing File: " & vbcrlf & err.Description & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & "Import Cancelled!!", vbCritical, "Error Importing/Opening File"
            Exit Function
            Else
            CustomizedPane_OnLoad
            Exit Function
            End If
        End if
        on error Goto 0
        Dim objWorksheet : Set objWorksheet = objExcel.Worksheets(1)
        objWorksheet.Activate
        Dim intRow : intRow = 2

        Dim XMLForList

        Dim intLinesRow : intLinesRow = 2
        XMLForList = "<ImportList>"
        Do Until objExcel.Cells(intLinesRow,1).Value = "" or objExcel.Cells(intLinesRow,1).Value = " "
            XMLForList = XMLForList & "<Item><StockCode>"& objExcel.Cells(intLinesRow, 1).Value &"</StockCode>"
            XMLForList = XMLForList & "<PriceCode>" & objExcel.Cells(intLinesRow,2).Value & "</PriceCode>"
            XMLForList = XMLForList & "<SellingPrice>" & objExcel.Cells(intLinesRow,3).Value & "</SellingPrice>"
            XMLForList = XMLForList & "<PriceBasis>" & objExcel.Cells(intLinesRow,4).Value & "</PriceBasis>"
            XMLForList = XMLForList & "<CommisionCode>" & objExcel.Cells(intLinesRow,5).Value & "</CommisionCode>"
            XMLForList = XMLForList & "<Import>1</Import>"
            XMLForList = XMLForList & "</Item>"
            intLinesRow = intLinesRow + 1
            Loop
        XMLForList = XMLForList & "</ImportList>"
        objExcel.Quit

        Dim ListXML
        ListXML = ListXML & "<Columns PrimaryNode='Item' Style='DataGrid' AutoSize='true' FreezeColumn='0' >"
        ListXML = ListXML & "<Column Name='StockCode' Description='Stock code' />"
        ListXML = ListXML & "<Column Name='PriceCode' Description='Price code' />"
        ListXML = ListXML & "<Column Name='SellingPrice' Description='Selling price' Type='Numeric' Alignment='Right' HdrAlignment='Right' Decimals='2' />"
        ListXML = ListXML & "<Column Name='PriceBasis' Description='Price basis' />"
        ListXML = ListXML & "<Column Name='CommisionCode' Description='Commision code' />"
        ListXML = ListXML & "<Column Name='Import' Description='Import' Type='checkbox' Editable='true' />"
        ListXML = ListXML & "</Columns>"
        CustomizedPane.CodeObject.ListviewProperties = ListXML
        CustomizedPane.CodeObject.ListviewData = XMLForList
        msgbox intLinesRow - 2 & " record/s read",vbInformation,"File Imported"
End Function

Function FileHandle(Action, ActVariable)
Dim Path : Path = SystemVariables.CodeObject.baseSettingsFolder & "ExcelImportPanePath.txt"
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

dim fso, ts
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Action = "WritePath" then
        Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(Path,2,False)
        ts.Write (ActVariable)
        ts.Close
Elseif Action = "DeletePath" then
                Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Path,1)
                Dim FilePathDP : FilePathDP = ts.ReadAll
                ts.Close
                fso.DeleteFile FilePathDP
Elseif Action = "ReadPath" then
                on error Resume Next
                Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Path,ForReading)
                Dim strLine
                Do Until ts.AtEndOfStream
                        strLine = ts.ReadLine
                Loop
                ts.close
                if Err then
                        FileHandle = "File Deleted"
                Else
                        FileHandle = strLine
                End if
                On Error Goto 0
Elseif Action = "Delete" then
                On Error Resume Next
                fso.DeleteFile Path
                If err then
                Exit Function
                End if
                On Error Goto 0
End if
End Function

Function CustomizedPane_OnLoad()
        Dim ListXML
        ListXML = ListXML & "<Columns PrimaryNode='Notify' Style='DataGrid' AutoSize='true' FreezeColumn='0' >"
        ListXML = ListXML & "<Column Name='Note' Description='NOTE' />"
        ListXML = ListXML & "</Columns>"
        CustomizedPane.CodeObject.ListviewProperties = ListXML

        Dim ShowNote
        ShowNote = "<Start>"
        ShowNote = ShowNote & "<Notify><Note>First Load the Excel File Path...</Note></Notify>"
        ShowNote = ShowNote & "</Start>"
        CustomizedPane.CodeObject.ListviewData = ShowNote
End Function

Function CustomizedPane_OnToolbarButton1Clicked()
    Dim MaxRows : MaxRows = Ubound(CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array, 2)
    If MaxRows = 0 OR CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array(0,0) = "First Load the Excel File Path..." then
        Exit Function
    Else
        Dim Counter
        Dim CLineCounter : CLineCounter = 0
        For Counter = 0 to MaxRows - 1
            If CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array(5, Counter) = "1" then
                                CLineCounter = CLineCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
                If CLineCounter = 0 then
                        msgbox "There was nothing selected to import.",vbInformation,"Importing..."
                        Exit Function
                Else
                msgbox CLineCounter & " record/s to be updated.",vbInformation,"Importing..."
                CallINVSPR
                End If
    End If
End Function

Function CallINVSPR()
        dim XMLOut, XMLParam, XMLDoc

        XMLParam = "<SetupInvPrice>"
        XMLParam = XMLParam & "  <Parameters>"
        XMLParam = XMLParam & "    <IgnoreWarnings>N</IgnoreWarnings>"
        XMLParam = XMLParam & "    <ApplyIfEntireDocumentValid>Y</ApplyIfEntireDocumentValid>"
        XMLParam = XMLParam & "    <ValidateOnly>N</ValidateOnly>"
        XMLParam = XMLParam & "  </Parameters>"
        XMLParam = XMLParam & "</SetupInvPrice>"

        XMLDoc = " <SetupInvPrice>"
        Dim MaxRows : MaxRows = Ubound(CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array, 2)
        Dim Counter
        Dim LineCounter : LineCounter = 0
        Dim CLineCounter : CLineCounter = 0
        For Counter = 0 to MaxRows - 1
                If CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array(5, Counter) = "1" then
                    XMLDoc = XMLDoc & "   <Item>"
                    XMLDoc = XMLDoc & "     <Key>"
                    XMLDoc = XMLDoc & "       <StockCode>" & CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array(0, Counter) & "</StockCode>"
                    XMLDoc = XMLDoc & "       <PriceCode>" & CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array(1, Counter) & "</PriceCode>"
                    XMLDoc = XMLDoc & "     </Key>"
                    XMLDoc = XMLDoc & "     <SellingPrice>" & CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array(2, Counter) & "</SellingPrice>"
                    XMLDoc = XMLDoc & "     <PriceBasis>" & CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array(3, Counter) & "</PriceBasis>"
                    XMLDoc = XMLDoc & "     <CommissionCode>" & CustomizedPane.CodeObject.Array(4, Counter) & "</CommissionCode>"
                    XMLDoc = XMLDoc & "   </Item>"
                    CLineCounter = CLineCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
        XMLDoc = XMLDoc & " </SetupInvPrice>"
        on error resume next
        XMLOut = CallSetup("INVSPR",XMLParam,XMLDoc,"Update","auto")
        if err then
          msgbox err.Description, vBCritical, "Calling Business Object"
          exit function
        end if
        ' Switch on error handling
        on error goto 0
        'msgbox CLineCounter & " rows updated"

        If Debug = "True" then
                Dim Path : Path = SystemVariables.CodeObject.baseSettingsFolder & "DEBUGExcelImportPane.txt"
                'Output XML to file
                dim fso, ts
                Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(Path,2,True)
                ts.Write ("XMLIn:" & vbCrlf & XMLDoc & vbCrlf &"XMLParam:" & vbCrlf & XMLParam & vbCrlf &"XMLOut:" & vbCrlf & XMLOut)
                ts.Close
                msgbox "Debug Done." & vbCrLf & " Check: "& Path
        End If
        ResultValidate XMLOut, "Update", CLineCounter
End Function

Function ResultValidate(XMLIn, Action, CLineCounter)
        Dim XMLDOM : Set XMLDOM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
        XMLDOM.Async = False
        XMLDOM.LoadXML(XMLIn)
        Dim ListXML

        Dim WarningMsgs : Set WarningMsgs = XMLDOM.GetElementsByTagName("ErrorDescription")
        Dim StkList
        If WarningMsgs.Length > 0 then
            StkList = "<List>"
            StkList = StkList & "<StockList>"
                StkList = StkList & "<Notes>Errors Found: " & WarningMsgs.Length & "</Notes>"
                StkList = StkList & "</StockList>"
            If WarningMsgs.Length > 0 then
                Dim WarnItems
                For Each WarnItems in WarningMsgs
                    StkList = StkList & "<StockList>"
                    StkList = StkList & "<Notes>Error in : " & WarnItems.ParentNode.NodeName & " - " & WarnItems.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Text & ": " & WarnItems.Text &"</Notes>"
                    StkList = StkList & "</StockList>"
                Next
            End If
            StkList = StkList & "</List>"
            ListXML = "<Columns PrimaryNode='StockList' Style='DataGrid' AutoSize='true' FreezeColumn='0' >"
            ListXML = ListXML & "<Column Name='Notes' Description='Notes' Link='false' />"
            ListXML = ListXML & "</Columns>"
        else
            StkList = "<List>"
            StkList = StkList & "<StockList>"
            StkList = StkList & "<Notes>No Errors Found..." & CLineCounter & " record/s updated</Notes>"
            StkList = StkList & "</StockList>"
            StkList = StkList & "</List>"
            ListXML = "<Columns PrimaryNode='StockList' Style='DataGrid' AutoSize='true' FreezeColumn='0' >"
            ListXML = ListXML & "<Column Name='Notes' Description='Notes' Link='false' />"
            ListXML = ListXML & "</Columns>"
        End If
        CustomizedPane.CodeObject.ListviewProperties = ListXML
        CustomizedPane.CodeObject.ListviewData = StkList
End Function
```

Perhaps if they have a test company try it out in there first so you can see what it's doing?

**NB:** This was done for SYSPRO 6.1 and 7. Minor updates may be required to make this work in other versions.
You can also check out the [SYSPRO Forums](http://forums.syspro.com/) for help relating to [syspro](/questions/tagged/syspro).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Chris - this is brilliant, I knew there would be a better solution to a direct update.....particularly as I spotted a table for price changes (which obviously wouldn't get updated). Thanks also for the links - very useful indeed - I'm currently awaiting approval for the forum.

Comment: I'm getting an error when refreshing the pane - 'Object doesn't support this property or method:'SystemVariables.CodeObject.baseSettingsFolder''. Could this be because Business Objects aren't licensed? The company is using Syspro 6.0.

Comment: I've tried to see what I can do to get the customized pane to work in 6.0 SP2 but unfortunately it is not possible.